# Layout: Creating a responsive 3 card layout

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, grid, tailwind-css

I am trying to achieve a layout where a big card is surrounded by 2 small cards in the same column but for medium & small screens to shift it be 2 columns one with the big card and the other containing only the 2 cards.

I don't know exactly how to structure my code in order to achieve this. Can anyone help plz?

Here is a snippet of what my code looks like

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
}
.small-card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
 }
 
 .big-card {
  height: 200px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  min-width: 250px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="small-card">Small card 1</div>
    <div class="big-card">Big Card</div>
    <div class="small-card">Small Crad 2</div>
</div>
```

**Big Screens:**

[image]

**Medium & Small Screens:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish what you want by adding a class like ".card" to all of your cards like the following:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card small-card">Small card 1</div>
    <div class="card big-card">Big Card</div>
    <div class="card small-card">Small Card 2</div>
</div>
```

And then use this media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

   .big-card {
     width: 100%;
   } 

   .container :nth-child(1){
     order: 1;
   }

   .container :nth-child(3) {
     order: 2;
   }

   .small-card {
     flex-grow: 1;
   }
}
```

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
}
.small-card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
 }
 
 .big-card {
  height: 200px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  min-width: 250px;
 }
 
 @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
   
   .big-card {
     width: 100%;
   }  
 
   .container :nth-child(1){
     order: 1;
   }
   
   .container :nth-child(3) {
     order: 2;
   }
   
   .small-card {
     flex-grow: 1;
   }
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card small-card">Small card 1</div>
    <div class="card big-card">Big Card</div>
    <div class="card small-card">Small Crad 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to be able to be of assistance!